# Is there a way to wrap an application on windows so that all all interactions with the OS can be observed and controlled?

Tags: c#, .net, c++, windows, windows-7

I have an application that I have to run on windows. I need a method to observe and control the interactions this application makes with windows. I need to observe the calls it makes, and the inputs it receives from the OS and I only need to change some of its inputs to suit my needs. Actually the more important part is changing the input (which depends on the situation). I was wondering what would be a good way to approach this? Should I try to run the application on a partial virtual machine that runs the application for windows and passes along all calls made by the application to windows and returns the input from windows? Or does windows provide some sort of API to do this?

Comment: Many debuggers can provide this level of functionality; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the simplest way to do it in my opinion is to use api-hooks and dll injection techniques. Check the book by Jeffrey Ritcher's (Programming Applications for Microsoft Windows) I think - don't remember exactly the name. Also check this 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/hooksys.aspx.
On linux you can use preload libs to do the same thing.

Comment: This one - http://www.amazon.co.uk/Programming-Applications-Windows-Microsoft/dp/1572319968/ref=sr_1_3?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1321959585&sr=1-3 ?

Comment: Yes should be. But this explain the dll injection techniques as I remember so for api hooks you have to search in google :).